# Check if AD user is blocked using PHP and adLDAP

Tags: php, ldap, adldap

I am trying to see if a user is disabled or not (using PHP and [adLDAP](http://adldap.sourceforge.net)). I can authenticate a user. The example I am using is this:

```
$user = 'jdoe'
$user_info=$adldap->user_info($user,array("useraccountcontrol"));
$enabled = (($user_info[0]['useraccountcontrol'][0] & 2) == 0);
```

The issue is that I always get 1 even for non-existing accounts. The example is taken from here: [adLDAP examples](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=api_examples)

I am connecting to LDAP as normal user. I do not have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the attribute useraccountcontrol is not declared in your AD schema for your objectclass user. Please verify your AD schema with ADSI edit or any schema viewer to make sure your objects have this attribute set.